# Angular | Remove active class on button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making an AngularJS project using Bootstrap.

Here's the JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mijacat/dmuuu79v/3/

I'd like to be able to toggle the button to have it instantly change back and forth from `.btn btn-default` to `.btn btn-info`. However, usually the button is 'active', then it changes state on a second click.

How can I do this in one click? Is there a solution using Angular if possible? This is because I'm hoping to change the button state to something different later.

Comment: Do you want to change a button class twice on a single click? Are you aware it will have a mostly unnoticeable effect in your UI?

Comment: Hi Marco. No. I meant when clicking, toggle the 'info' class and clicking again toggles the 'default' class. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Doesn't your code in jsfiddle already behaves that way?

Comment: How about [bootstrap's implementation of stateful buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio) ? They are taking advantage of the checkbox behavior which is the actual html element with a toggle behaviour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass):

```
<button class="btn" ng-class="{'btn-info': some_condition}">...</button>
```

Here's an updated JSFiddle (also note the usage of `$index` variable): https://jsfiddle.net/dmuuu79v/4/

Comment: Thanks, this is my first project using Angular. I'll take note of the `$index` variable!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that you have a one variable `$scope.isToggled` to keep the state of all buttons. You should keep it separate.

I have corrected your fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dmuuu79v/5/